# Piping WSL commands stop randomly

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

This works:

```
wsl
cat * | sort | uniq
```

But this seems to randomly stop early:

```
wsl cat * | wsl sort | wsl uniq
```

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

---

This works:

```
wsl cat * | wsl sort >temp
wsl uniq <temp
```

But this randomly stops early again:

```
wsl cat * >temp
wsl sort <temp | wsl uniq
```

---

The problem seems to manifest only with "many" (e.g. 100) "large" (e.g. 300 lines of 50 characters each) text files.

For example this `.bat` file can be used to create the `*` files that trigger the problem:

```
@echo off
echo "See a pin and pick it up, and, all day long, you'll have a pin." > data.txt
FOR /L %%j IN (1,1,3) DO (
    FOR /L %%k IN (1,1,100) DO (
        echo "Sooner or later all things are numbers, yes? %%k" >> data.txt
    )
)
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,100) DO (
    copy data.txt data%%i.txt
)
```

Comment: What is the Windows 10 full version? What is in `*`? Are those **only** text files?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Windows 10 Version 1803 (17134.765) Yes, only text files. The problem seems to manifest only with "many" (e.g. 100) "large" (e.g. 300 lines of 50 characters each) files.

Comment: @Peter - Update your Question

Comment: @Ramhound - I updated my question.